# How to select multiple users for Messaging system in php

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

I am working in PHP&HTMl for messaging system. For that to get the user list from db, I have used select query and while loop to listout the username in html dropdown.
My question was, how can i select two or more user at a time to send messages to them. Can anyone guide me in this regards.

```
<div class="content">
<h1>New Personnal Message</h1>
<form action="message.php" method="post">
    Please fill the following form to send a personnal message.<br /><br />
    <label>Title</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="text">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($otitle, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>" id="title" name="title" /><br /><br /></div>

    <label for="recip">Recipient<span class="small">&nbsp;(Username)</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="text">
    <input type='checkbox' onclick="checkall()" id="selectall">
    <?php 
    $sql2 = "SELECT fname FROM REGISTRATIONFORM";

    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);


    echo "<select name='username'>";
    while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<option value='".$row['fname']."'>" .$row['fname']."</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>
    <br /><br />
    </div>
    <?php
    else
    {

    ?>

    <label for="recip">Recipient<span class="small">&nbsp;(Username)</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="text">
    <input type="text" readonly value="<?php echo $email; ?>" id="recip" name="recip" /><br /><br /></div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <label for="message">Message</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="text">
    <textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="message" name="message"><?php echo htmlentities($omessage, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></textarea></div><br /><br />
    <div class="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-info"/><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

add multiple attribute to select to be like this

```
 echo "<select name='username[]' multiple>";
```

use CTRL+click to select more

if your question is how to send mail using php you can find more here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mail_mail.asp

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing which is to be keep in mind when dealing with multi-select dropdown:

```
echo "<select name='username[]' multiple>";
```

the `name` of multi-select dropdown must be an `array` so that it can hold multiple values in it. And multiple attribute is also mentioned in it.

And you can get its value in php like:

```
$usernames = $_REQUEST['username'];
foreach($usernames as $username)
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @mayank. How do i need to get these username values using post method storing insert the values the DB.